# C# Lambda Cognito: Missing required parameter USERNAME

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to C#.

I am trying to create a Lambda that takes a `Username` and `Password` which is checked against a Cognito User Pool and then returns an auth token.

Here is the code:

```cs
namespace CognitoUser.AuthenticateProfile;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;

using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider;
using Amazon.CognitoIdentityProvider.Model;
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Users.Models;


public class Function
{
    private readonly AmazonCognitoIdentityProviderClient _client = new();

    private const string ClientId = "123"; // ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CLIENT_ID"];

    public async Task<APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse> Function(CognitoUser input, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        LambdaLogger.Log($"Calling function name: {context.FunctionName}\n");
        {
            LambdaLogger.Log($"Attempting to get token for {input.UserName}\n");
            String token = await GetToken(input.UserName, input.Password);
            APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyResponse response = new()
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK,
                Body = token,
                Headers = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "Content-Type", "text/plain" } }
            };
            return response;
        }
    }
    private async Task<string>  GetToken (string userName, string password) { 
        InitiateAuthRequest authReq = new ()
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
        };
        authReq.AuthParameters.Add("USERNAME", userName);
        authReq.AuthParameters.Add("PASSWORD", password);
        InitiateAuthResponse authResp = await _client.InitiateAuthAsync(authReq);
        // Look into exceptions etc 
        return authResp.AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
    }
}
```

When I use the below payload in the Lambda console it works as expected, but when I try to make a `POST` request from the API Gateway Console I get the following:

```sh
Thu Mar 24 19:00:50 UTC 2022 : Endpoint response body before transformations: {
  "errorType": "InvalidParameterException",
  "errorMessage": "Missing required parameter USERNAME",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionStream(IRequestContext requestContext, IWebResponseData httpErrorResponse, HttpErrorResponseException exception, Stream responseStream)",
    "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseExceptionHandler.HandleExceptionAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, HttpErrorResponseException exception)",
    "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ExceptionHandler`1.HandleAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)",
    "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.ProcessExceptionAsync(IExecutionContext executionContext, Exception exception)",
    "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.ErrorHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)",
    "at Amazon.Runtime.Internal.CallbackHandler.InvokeAsync[T](IExecutionContext executionContext)",
    "at Amazon.Runtime.Inte [TRUNCATED]
Thu Mar 24 19:00:50 UTC 2022 : Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function error: Missing required parameter USERNAME. Lambda request id: fb739e08-aa93-4283-a8e3-c6bc68d730c2
Thu Mar 24 19:00:50 UTC 2022 : Method completed with status: 502
```

Comment: make sure that USER_PASSWORD_AUTH is enabled.
go to user pool - > app clients - >show details -> Enable username password auth for admin APIs for authentication (ALLOW_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD_AUTH).

Comment: @BasilKosovan I have tried that, but get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

[USER_PASSWORD_AUTH](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html): Non-SRP authentication flow; USERNAME and PASSWORD are passed directly. If a user migration Lambda trigger is set, this flow will invoke the user migration Lambda if it doesn't find the USERNAME in the user pool.

```
InitiateAuthRequest authReq = new ()
{
    UserPoolId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["USERPOOL_ID"],
    ClientId = ClientId,
    AuthFlow = AuthFlowType.USER_PASSWORD_AUTH
};
```

The user pool ID set up in the prerequisites section and your have to pass this user pool ID in above request.

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-csharp-to-register-and-authenticate-with-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Comment: I get a cannot resolve UserPoolId

Comment: @Bob https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-csharp-to-register-and-authenticate-with-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Comment: Can you update your answer, as you got the bounty, but its wrong.

Comment: Your problem was "InvalidParameterException". Isn't it solved? You are now getting "cannot resolve UserPoolId ", that is another issue. The USERPOOL_ID and IDENTITYPOOL_ID are the user pool ID and identity pool ID that you set up in the prerequisites section. follow my link to get detail about this new issue.... https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/use-csharp-to-register-and-authenticate-with-amazon-cognito-user-pools/

Comment: No, so your answer is not valid, you can't pass UserPoodId into authReq so the code doesn't even compile and the IDE complains about UserPoolID not being recognised